# Azure Logic App - Write Salesforce records to a blob

Tags: salesforce, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am new to azure logic app and am trying to develop our first logic app in the designer. The goal is simple - connect to our salesforce production instance and extract data from an object. Write that data to a delimited file in our storage container - from where the data warehouse can ingest the file.

The first steps are pretty straight forward - i added a recurrence trigger and connected a salesforce Get Records action to it. Chose the User object in salesforce for now because its got minimal data.

Executed the logic app and it runs fine. I can see the data extracted is correct.

However now I am lost as to how to create a delimited file in the container. I obviously could not connect the Create Blob action directly to the Get Records action. Based on some documentation i tried creating a CSV table first but got an error saying that an Array is expected but the Get Records action returns an object.

If anyone has faced something similar and has any pointers, documentation would appreciate it. Thanks in advance for any help

Regards
Sid

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you’re getting from SalesForce? Obfuscate data where need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Get records object will have 2 objects '@odata.context' and 'value'. The 'value' field will have actual array of records, so you need to use the value.
Please refer below screenshot of the logic app that works, fetched record from user object and stored as delimited csv file.
[image]

Here is output screenshot for create csv table: [image]